# Packages for looking up Twitter data

Tags: twitter, topic-modeling, tweets, rtweet

I'm looking for a package that can look up Tweets by date. I'm currently using rtweets where I can look up the last Tweets (18,000 at a time) with certain hashtags or users. But I want to look up Tweets within a range of dates. Any idea of a good way to do that?